# HighcharteR: tooltip does not show correct x-axis value

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I've been working quite a lot with HighcharteR but this one has me baffled.

I'm trying to include the x-axis category in the tooltip, but instead of displaying the character value, it's giving me a numeric value instead.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame("group" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                 "value" = c(1,3,2,4,5,4),
                 "period" = c("Baseline","Pulse 1","Pulse 2",
                              "Baseline","Pulse 1","Pulse 2"))

hchart(df, 
       type="line", 
       hcaes(x = period, y = value, group = group)
  ) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "{point.y} is the value for 
                            group {series.name} for {point.x}.")
```

As you can see, the tooltip *header* correctly shows `Baseline`, `Pulse 1`, and `Pulse 2`, but the tooltip itself displays `0`, `1`, and `2`. The Highcharts documentation says the tooltip header normally accesses it using `point.key`, but that doesn't work either.

Anybody know what's going on? What's the correct way of calling the x-axis category here?

Comment: Use `point.name`. See [this github issue](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/54)

Comment: I thought I had already tried every possible permutation including this one, but clearly not. Confusing to not have it work with plain `point.x` but glad to have the solution now. Thanks!